# DBFlow and Butterknife Conflict

Tags: java, android, orm, butterknife, dbflow

Someone knows how can I use DBFlow and ButterKnife without conflict? I'm having  the following problem when I use these libraries together:

**"Caused by: com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.InvalidDBConfiguration: Model object: br.com.test.Name is not registered with a Database. Did you forget an annotation?"**

I implemented the annotations in .java correctly, how can we see:

```
   package br.com.test;

   import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Column;
   import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.PrimaryKey;
   import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Table;
   import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.BaseModel;

   @Table(database = DatabaseInfo.class)
   public class Name extends BaseModel {

       @Column
       @PrimaryKey
       long id;

       @Column
       String value;

       public Name() {}
   }
```

When I remove ButterKnife dependencies from .gradle and .java, the same code works fine.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Are you using the latest butterknife?

Comment: Hi Rod_Algonquin I'm using the version 8.4.0. "compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'", it's not last version

Comment: try using 8.5.1

Comment: You are right Rod_Algonquin, I changed to 8.5.1 and works. ButterKnife are using annotationProcessor too like DBFlow instead apt. I think that exist some conflict when we use apt together annotationProcessor. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Road_Algonquin said to me, we have to check ButterKnife version. When I changed:

```
//FROM

apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'

//TO

annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
```

Works fine